# Other values to define than Page.Title?

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages

I have a `Site.master` page where I put my header, my nav-bar, my footer ...
I just discovered `Page.Title` that allow to define a title from your 
page_number_one.aspx.cs like

```
    //page_number_one.aspx.cs
             Page.Title = "Home";
```

and in site.master is like

```
    //page_number_one.aspx
<h2><%: Page.Title %></h2>
```

But if I need more values to put in my site.master and to define them in my .aspx.cs ? What can I use ?

```
    //page_number_one.aspx.cs
int filenumber = 4;
Page.MetaDescription = filenumber
```

and

```
    //page_number_one.aspx
<%: Page.MetaDescription %>
```

look like good to begin, but my values will probably not be description. (Edit) More than Subtitle or Files Number, or User Name...
Anything you can think about ?

Comment: You need to be more specific. What kind of values, and how would you like to use them on master?

Comment: This is quite broad as it stands.. My knowledge of ASP.NET is fairly limited, but I'm assuming there are quite a few of these values and you seem to be asking for a list, and no particular issue to be solved.

Comment: You can access any public or protected properties of the [`Page` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page_properties(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ypu can use the master page public variables in content pages. For example

```
((Site1)this.Master).filenumber=2;
```

You can set any values like this